# php notice database array error

Tags: javascript, php

If I press on my post button the data of my form will be send to the database but I get 2 Array to string error's. I don't know what I have to change to fix these errors.

Here is also a picture of the data in my database where it is showing arrays.

https://gyazo.com/f7463825b6ae2e44812d5149d55e9011

I hope someone can help me! I am learning :P

Here is my code example.

```html
    <html>
    <title>HOTEL</title>
    <center>

        <head>
            <h2>
                <?php echo "Welkom terug " . $_SESSION["username"] . ""?>
                </br>
                <a href='logout.php'>Log uit</a></br>
            </h2>
            <hr>
            <h1>Film toevoegen</h1>
            <hr>
        </head>

        <body>
            <form method="POST">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Film:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="txtFilm"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Genre:</td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="Genre">
       <option value="Actie">Actie</option>
                            <option value="Fantasie">Fantasie</option>
                            <option value="Horror">Horror</option>
       <option value="Avontuur">Avontuur</option>
       <option value="Komedie">Komedie</option>
                            <option value="Romantiek">Romantiek</option>
                            <option value="Historisch">Historisch</option>
      </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Film omschrijving:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="txtFilmomschrijving"></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Datum van uitkomst: </td>
                        <td><input type="date" name="uitkomstdate">

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Datum uit bioscoop: </td>
                        <td><input type="date" name="BiosDate">

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr></tr>
                    <tr></tr>
                    <tr></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Film draai dagen: </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="Maandag" name="draaidag[]">Maandag
                            <input type="checkbox" value="Dinsdag" name="draaidag[]">Dinsdag
                            <input type="checkbox" value="Woensdag" name="draaidag[]">Woensdag
                            <input type="checkbox" value="Donderdag" name="draaidag[]">Donderdag
                            <input type="checkbox" value="Vrijdag" name="draaidag[]">Vrijdag
                            <input type="checkbox" value="Zaterdag" name="draaidag[]">Zaterdag
                            <input type="checkbox" value="Zondag" name="draaidag[]">Zondag
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Film tijd dagen: </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="12uur" name="tijddagen[]">12:00
                            <input type="checkbox" value="14uur" name="tijddagen[]">14:00
                            <input type="checkbox" value="16uur" name="tijddagen[]">16:00
                            <input type="checkbox" value="18uur" name="tijddagen[]">18:00
                            <input type="checkbox" value="20uur" name="tijddagen[]">20:00
                            <input type="checkbox" value="22uur" name="tijddagen[]">22:00
                            <input type="checkbox" value="24uur" name="tijddagen[]">24:00
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Zaal: </td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="zaal">
       <option value="normaal">Normaal</option>
                            <option value="groot">Groot</option>
      </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>


                    <tr></tr>
                    <tr></tr>
                    <tr></tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" value="Film toevoegen" name="btnHuur" />
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
            <hr>
            <?php
  if(isset($_POST['btnHuur']))
  {?>
            <table>
                <th>
                    <h2>Toegevoegde film:</h2>
                </th>

                <?php
    if(isset($_POST['btnHuur']))
    {
     ?>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo 'Film: '; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $_POST['txtFilm']; ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo 'Genre: '; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $_POST['Genre']; ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo 'Film omschrijving: '; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $_POST['txtFilmomschrijving'];?>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo 'Datum van uitkomst: ';?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $_POST['uitkomstdate']; ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo 'Datum uit bioscoop: ';?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $_POST['BiosDate']; ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo 'Film draai dagen: ';?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php
    if(!empty($_POST['draaidag']))
    {
     foreach($_POST['draaidag']as$check)
     {
      echo " ".$check;
      $draaidag = " ".$check;
     }
     ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                
                 <tr>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo 'Film tijd dagen: ';?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php
    if(!empty($_POST['tijddagen']))
    {
     foreach($_POST['tijddagen']as$check)
     {
      echo " ".$check;
      $tijddagen = " ".$check;
     }
                }
     ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                
                 <tr>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo 'zaal: '; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $_POST['zaal']; ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                
                
                
                
                
                
                
                
                
                
                <?php
         
    }else
    {
     echo "Geen";
    }
     include("loginDB.php");
     ?>
                    </br>
                    </br>
                    </br>
                    <?php
     $film = $_POST['txtFilm'];
     $genre = $_POST['Genre'];
     $Filmomschrijving = $_POST['txtFilmomschrijving'];
     $Datumvanuitkomst = $_POST['uitkomstdate'];//$_POST['selDag'] + '-' + $_POST['selMaand'] + '-' + $_POST['selJaar'];
     $Datumuitbioscoop = $_POST['BiosDate'];//$_POST['selDag'] + '-' + $_POST['selMaand'] + '-' + $_POST['selJaar'];
     $Filmdraaidagen = $_POST['draaidag'];
     $Filmtijddragen = $_POST['tijddagen'];
     $Zaal = $_POST['zaal'];
     ?>
                        <tr></tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <?php
     if($film && $genre && $Filmomschrijving && $Datumvanuitkomst && $Filmdraaidagen && $Filmtijddragen && $Zaal)
     {
      $query = "INSERT INTO films VALUES (0, '$film', '$genre', '$Filmomschrijving', '$Datumvanuitkomst', '$Datumuitbioscoop', '$Filmdraaidagen', '$Filmtijddragen', '$Zaal')";
       mysqli_query($db, $query);
       echo "Bestelling voltooid!";
     }
    }
   ?>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

            </table>
            <hr>
            <?php } ?>

        </body>
    </center>

    </html>
```

Comment: the error line is Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\Opdrachten\BioscoopRenesse\Filmstoevoegen.php on line 259       Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\Opdrachten\BioscoopRenesse\Filmstoevoegen.php on line 259

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is some mistake in your Php Code,

Html You had define name as `Array` (`draaidag[]` && `tijddagen[]`)

```
<tr>
   <td>Film draai dagen: </td>
   <td>
     <input type="checkbox" value="Maandag" name="draaidag[]">Maandag
     <input type="checkbox" value="Dinsdag" name="draaidag[]">Dinsdag
     <input type="checkbox" value="Woensdag" name="draaidag[]">Woensdag
     <input type="checkbox" value="Donderdag" name="draaidag[]">Donderdag
     <input type="checkbox" value="Vrijdag" name="draaidag[]">Vrijdag
     <input type="checkbox" value="Zaterdag" name="draaidag[]">Zaterdag
    <input type="checkbox" value="Zondag" name="draaidag[]">Zondag
 </td>
</tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Film tijd dagen: </td>
    <td>
       <input type="checkbox" value="12uur" name="tijddagen[]">12:00
       <input type="checkbox" value="14uur" name="tijddagen[]">14:00
       <input type="checkbox" value="16uur" name="tijddagen[]">16:00
       <input type="checkbox" value="18uur" name="tijddagen[]">18:00
       <input type="checkbox" value="20uur" name="tijddagen[]">20:00
       <input type="checkbox" value="22uur" name="tijddagen[]">22:00
       <input type="checkbox" value="24uur" name="tijddagen[]">24:00
   </td>
</tr>
```

You need to use [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) while accessing from `$_POST`. to convert it into `string`.

```
$Filmdraaidagen = implode("," ,$_POST['draaidag']);
$Filmtijddragen = implode(",",$_POST['tijddagen']);
```